# Highlight opening and closing tags xhtml in emacs just like notepad++

Tags: xml, emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

I really find convenient with the feature of highlighting opening and closing tag in XHTML document in Notepad++. Is there any equivalent feature in Emacs? I am using Emacs 24.3.1

[image]

Comment: What's the face now? Which mode in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the editor to show you the closing tag when you cursor over its opening mate and vice versa.  One way to get that is to install [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki) and execute `M-x show-smartparens-mode`.

Comment: Cool.  If you feel this answer was the best one, please select the check mark next to it to mark it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/deactivated/hl-tags-mode) package.  It does not do exactly what you want (I think, I never used notepad++), but maybe it is good enough for you.